# Xcode 14: Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile, build-error, xcode14

I'm encountering an issue with Xcode 14 where I'm getting the error message "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" during the build process.

[image]

This error prevents me from running the app on a device or simulator. I have tried various solutions but haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Here are some details about my setup:

Xcode version: 14.3.1

Provisioning profiles: I have verified that the correct provisioning profile is selected in the project settings.

Certificates: I have valid development and distribution certificates installed.

Code signing settings: I have checked and reconfigured the code signing settings in my project, ensuring the correct bundle identifier, provisioning profile, and certificates are used.

Despite these efforts, I'm still facing the "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" error. Are there any specific troubleshooting steps or common solutions that I might be overlooking? What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Simulator does not use code signing, so you must have another problem like missing framework.